# getDatabase called recursively on Seed

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Im trying to seed my sqlite database with testdata in `onCreate` method in my `SqliteOpenHelper`... However, it doesn't matter why I try it still won't work.. Im getting `getDatabase` called recursively.

This is the code of my SqliteOpenHelper class..

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_CONTACT);
        SeedData();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.d("ContactDbHelper", "Create Database failed" + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void SeedData() {

    db = getWritableDatabase();

    Contact contact = new Contact("Test1", "CEO/Founder", "http://test.se/system/data/6816/medium/test1.jpg", "blalblalblalblalblalbalbalallbalabalalbalb");
    // Create ContentValues
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(ContactContract.Contact.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_NAME, contact.getName());
    contentValues.put(ContactContract.Contact.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_PROFESSION, contact.getProfession());
    contentValues.put(ContactContract.Contact.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_URL, contact.getUrl());
    contentValues.put(ContactContract.Contact.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_DESCRIPTION, contact.getDescription());

    // Insert values into Contact table rows
    db.insert(
            ContactContract.Contact.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            contentValues
    );

    Contact contact2 = new Contact("Test2", "Employee", "http://test2.se/system/data/6816/medium/test2.jpg", "asdadsadadadadasdasdadsasds");
    // Create ContentValues
    ContentValues contentValues2 = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(ContactContract.Contact.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_NAME, contact.getName());
    contentValues.put(ContactContract.Contact.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_PROFESSION, contact.getProfession());
    contentValues.put(ContactContract.Contact.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_URL, contact.getUrl());
    contentValues.put(ContactContract.Contact.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_DESCRIPTION, contact.getDescription());

    // Insert values into Contact table rows
    db.insert(
            ContactContract.Contact.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            contentValues2
    );

}
```

Is there any other way to insert multiple rows with data, or any other approach to seed? I don't like plain sql-queries, I still wanna use SqliteDatabase `db.insert()`

I also tried creating custom Insert method and called it form SeedData method but got recursive error again:

```
// Create
public long Insert(Contact contact){
    db = getWritableDatabase();

    // Create ContentValues
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(ContactContract.Contact.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_NAME, contact.getName());
    contentValues.put(ContactContract.Contact.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_PROFESSION, contact.getProfession());
    contentValues.put(ContactContract.Contact.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_URL, contact.getUrl());
    contentValues.put(ContactContract.Contact.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_DESCRIPTION, contact.getDescription());

    // Insert values into Contact table rows
    long contactId = db.insert(
            ContactContract.Contact.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            contentValues);

    // Return generated id from database
    return contactId;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `db = getWritableDatabase();`. This is causing the looping.

Pass `SQLiteDatabase` as an argument to `SeedData(SQLiteDatabase db)` in `onCreate` method

Comment: Omg, why didn't I notice that.. haha! Ill make it correct answer asap :)